# C# Generic Repository

Tags: c#, generics

I am trying to implement a generic repository but I am snagged. Here is a summary of my object model. The problem is that the concrete repository, "UserAccountRepositoryStub" will not compile. The error is:

> The type User has to be convertible to type IRepository...

IRepostory:

```
    public interface IRepository<T> where T : IEntity
{
...
}
```

Abstract Repository:

```
public class AbstractRepository<T> where T : class, IEntity, IRepository<T> {...}
```

IUserAccountRepository:

```
public interface IUserAccountRepository
```

User:

```
public class User : IEntity{...}
```

UserRepositoryStub(concrete):

```
public class UserAccoutRepositoryStub : AbstractRepository<User>, IUserAccountRepository
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The definition of `AbstractRepository<T>` should probably be

```
public class AbstractRepository<T> : IRepository<T> where T : class, IEntity {...}
```

because you want the repository to implement `IRepository<T>` not the objects in it, right?

Answer (score 1):

Your `AbstractRepository` requires that `T` is of type `IRepository<T>`. Did you mean to do:

```
public class AbstractRepository<T> : IRepository<T> where T : class, IEntity,  {...}
```

Answer (score 1):

On your AbstractRepository you've got the IRepository in the wrong spot. Everything after the "where" and before the "{...}" specifies the generic constraints. To specify inheritence you need to put it before the where.

Try this instead

```
public class AbstractRepository<T> : IRepository<T> where T : class, IEntity {...}
```